# Adding gesture recognizers in MGLAnnotationImage?

Tags: swift, mapbox, uigesturerecognizer, gesture, uitapgesturerecognizer

So here is my imageFor Mapbox function:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, imageFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationImage? {
        var reuseid = ""
        switch annotation.subtitle ?? "" {
        case "uno":
            reuseid = "uno"
        case "dos":
            reuseid = "dos"
        case "tres":
            reuseid = "tres"
        default:
            reuseid = "default"
        }
        var annotationImage = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationImage(withIdentifier: reuseid)
        
        if annotationImage == nil {
            guard let image = UIImage(named: reuseid) else { return nil }
            annotationImage = MGLAnnotationImage(image: image, reuseIdentifier: reuseid)
            let tapGesture = AnnotationTapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Coordinator.tappedAnnotation(sender:)))
            tapGesture.annotation = annotation as! MGLPointAnnotation
            annotationImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture) //error on this line says 'Value of type 'MGLAnnotationImage?' has no member 'addGestureRecognizer''
        }
        return annotationImage
    }

class AnnotationTapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer {
    var annotation = MGLPointAnnotation()
}
```

How do I make it so that I can add a gesture recognizer to the annotationImage I'm returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning an `MGLAnnotationImage`, return an `MGLAnnotationView`, which is just a subclass of `UIView`. You can attach a gesture recognizer to that.

To simplify things let's subclass `MGLAnnotationView` and create our custom marker. This marker is nothing fancy, just an image (50 x 50 points) that of course is tappable with our custom recognizer. To do that I just effectively made the marker a `UIButton`. When the user taps on this marker, the marker will call the `didSelectMarker(point:)` method on the delegate.

```
class XAnnotationView: MGLAnnotationView {
    weak var delegate: XMapMarkerDelegate?
    var point: MGLPointAnnotation?

    required override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
        let button = UIButton(frame: rect)
        let image = UIImage(named: "mapMarker")

        button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        button.setImage(image, for: .selected)
        button.setImage(image, for: .highlighted)
        button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(markerAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        frame = rect
        addSubview(button)
        isEnabled = false // disable it if we're adding our own gesture recognizer
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        return nil
    }

    @objc private func markerAction() {
        delegate?.didSelectMarker(point: point)
    }
}
```

The `XMapMarkerDelegate` delegate is something we just made up so let's define it by creating a protocol that any class object can conform to, likely a `UIViewController`, to handle this method. Any view controller that conforms to this protocol can now handle these tap events.

```
protocol XMapMarkerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didSelectMarker(point: MGLPointAnnotation)
}
```

Then whichever class object is displaying our map, likely a `UIViewController`, conform it to our custom protocol and handle the touch event. This object will likely be the same object that is the map's delegate, so let's just group them together for neater organization:

```
extension SomeViewController: MGLMapViewDelegate, XMapMarkerDelegate {
    /* This is one of Mapbox's many delegate methods.
       This method is for adding annotation views to the map. */
    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MGLPointAnnotation { // only handle point annotations
            if let reusable = dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "marker") as? XAnnotationView { // find a reusable marker if one is available with the given identifier
                reusable.point = annotation // assign this marker the current point
                return reusable
            } else { // if no reusable marker found, create a new marker with the given identifier
                let new = XAnnotationView(reuseIdentifier: "marker")
                new.delegate = self // assign self as the delegate
                new.point = annotation // assign this marker the current point
                return new
            }
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    /* This is our custom delegate method. */
    func didSelectMarker(point: MGLPointAnnotation) {
        print("did tap marker")
    }
}
```

You can customize this as much as you want to add custom data or objects to the marker. You can create multiple subclasses of the annotation view, each with a different size or image, and use different ones on the map depending on the annotation point. The possibilities are almost limitless.

Comment: I think I might HAVE to return the MGLAnnotationImage because the imageFor function is built into the coordinator delegate protocol for Mapbox. Do you have a specific implementation that has worked for you in the past?

Comment: I can post some code if you want but Mapbox has a delegate method specifically for returning `MGLAnnotationView` so you would use that in place of the one you're currently using. They work the same way, one just deals with images and the other views.

Comment: If I try to put the code in imageFor into viewFor, I get an error that says "Cannot convert return expression of type 'MGLAnnotationImage?' to return type 'MGLAnnotationView?'"...I know this is because I'm explicitly initializing an instance of MGLAnnotationImage, but I'm doing that because it has the key property of image that I need for my custom annotation images...if you add some code, it might help others in the future who have the same issue :)

Comment: also let me know if there is anything I can add to my source code to help!

Comment: I did some customizing, and it ended up working quite well, thank you :) Is there any way to create the default Mapbox icon inside this button that is returned?

Comment: Mapbox recommends custom markers for custom map data and we’re using a custom annotation view but you can download them from Mapbox and add them to your asset catalog https://docs.mapbox.com/help/getting-started/add-markers/

Comment: Side note: If you aren’t very good at creating custom assets then consider looking for free PNG map markers online.